SLURM: launching GPU jobs across nodes from within python
I am trying to run a python script that evaluates another function for different parameter values, and does this N times. The function evaluations are independent, and I want to run each on a single GPU. I am running this on a cluster, where the runscript for my main python file looks something like this
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -N 12  
#SBATCH -C gpu  
#SBATCH -G 48  
#SBATCH -q regular

module load pytorch  
srun --exact -N 1 -G 0 -n 1 --cpu_bind=cores python run_main.py

Then, in run_main.py, I have a loop
for i in range(N):
    processes = []
    for k in range(48): #i.e. one task per gpu
        cmd = "srun --exact --ntasks=1 -G 1 -N 1 --cpu-bind=none python run_task.py (with a bunch of arguments depending on k, etc)"
            print(cmd)
            process = Popen(cmd, shell=True)
            processes.append(process)  
        for process in processes:
            process.wait()  
    #do something else depending on run_task outcomes, and then launch over GPUs again

This seems to be way too slow for how quick the individual tasks should run, so I assume there either is a lot of overhead, or I'm not using all my GPUs at the same time. How can I check for this? How could I do this better?
